# Alexa location permission request is not working

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Whenever I request a location permission in the alexa simulator, the simulator does not respond. 
I use the code snippet below.

How does the intent look like to process the response?

```
conv._alexaContext!.response.speak(reasonForLocationPermissionText + ', muss ich zuerst deinen aktuellen Standort aus deinem Alexa‐Konto abrufen. Bist du damit einverstanden?')
const permissions = ['read::alexa:device:all:address']
conv._alexaContext!.response.askForPermissionsConsentCard(permissions)
conv._alexaContext!.emit(':responseReady')
```

Comment: I'd check your skill logs. I know some things (like reminders) aren't available in the simulator so it might be similar with the location permission. But also requests for some permissions are sent to the app, not as part of the conversation flow and a subsequent intent so perhaps you need to check there.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Can you please tell me how to test your alexa skill on a real device, so I can check if the permission request is done?

Comment: Well if you've got a real device linked to your developer account you should be able to test it on that. As I say, check the logs first to see if there's an error there about the permissions. Also check in the alexa app to see if you have a permission request in there under the activity section

Comment: thx for the hint. I did both already - permission activated and looked in the logs. But no errors logged there. Which app do you use to get alexa run on your phone?

Comment: There's an official alexa app which is a companion to an actual echo device. It's where activity cards etc. get sent

Comment: can you please send a link to this app, so I can be sure that I use the right app?

Comment: For some reason it won't let me copy paste the link on my phone. I'm on iOS so just search "Amazon Alexa" in the iOS app store and it should be the first non-sponsored result

Comment: ok, my alexa skill worked within the app. And now the consent card appears. But what to to from this step? I activated the location permission already, but don't know what to say when the card comes up?

Comment: If you’ve granted the permission in the card you should now be able to relaunch your Alexa skill and you should see the permission granted so now you can use it

Comment: a screen appears, that tells me that my skill asks me to aggree with the permissions. In the alexa app you can find further information.

There's no silde button to enable the permisson.